# Querying merged pull requests whose head branches still exist

Tags: graphql, github-api

I have a GraphQL query that lists merged and closed pull requests (by asking for a pull request's `headRef` I can tell whether its branch exists):

```
{
  organization(login: "company") {
    repository(name: "repo") {
      pullRequests(last: 100, states: [CLOSED, MERGED]) {
        nodes {
          headRef {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to get all pull requests whose headRef is not null (e.g. I wish I could do something like `pullRequests(last: 100, states: [CLOSED, MERGED], headRef not null)`). Is it possible, or should I continue to discard null headRefs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like [I can't query only non-null headRefs](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-API-Development-and/How-would-I-delete-all-merged-or-closed-PR-branches-with-the/td-p/39639) after all.